# Uploading large files in WCF, using streaming mode

Tags: wcf, streaming

Hello i have a problem uploading a file using wcf and streaming. When i switch from transferMode="Streamed" to "Buffered" on the client it works, though not streamed, but no exception. When i switch the client to "Streamed" it fails. I have been fghting with this for hours now, and just maxed out all the sizes so that doesnt fail. I cant seem to find whats going wrong. Can anyone spot it?

I have a service with the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GreenWebManagerServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="GreenWebManagerServiceBehavior" name="GreenWebManagerService.ManagerService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:50036/GreenWebManagerService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GreenWebManagerServiceBinding" contract="GreenWebManagerService.IGWManagerService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GreenWebManagerServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and a client with the following configuration:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGWManagerService" closeTimeout="10:01:00"
                        openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
                        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
                        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                        <security mode="None">
                            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                                realm="" />
                            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                        </security>
                    </binding>
                </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:50036/GWManagerService.svc"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGWManagerService"
                    contract="ManagerService.IGWManagerService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGWManagerService" />
            </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
```

I get the following error and stacktrace, please note that the numbers are bytes read i write to console:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
256
4352
69888
135424
200960
266496
332032
397568
463104
528640
594176
659712
725248
790784
856320
921856
987392
1052928
1118464
1184000
1249536
1315072
1380608
1446144
1511680
1577216
1642752
1708288
1773824
1839360
1904896
1970432
2002629
2002629
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.TargetInvocationException'
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl'
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance'
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your exception starts as a wpf xaml loader exception.

It appears that you are trying to stream that data directly into a WPF control. It could be that this is the problem.

Depending on what you are doing, you could try to stream the data to the client. Then when the data is all over, bind it to the WPF control.

Comment: My upload client is WPF client, so it opens a stream and sends it to the WCF service (.svc) hosted within cassini